# Can I query download manager from 3rd party app?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am running the following setup on a rooted phone.

App A is using DownloadManager in order to download a file. App B parses the phone's logs and catches the enqueue ID of the download App A has issued.
Can App B query the DownloadManager and get the state of the file Downloaded by App A?

When I used the following code in App B with the enqueue ID the cursor returns empty.

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
query.setFilterById(enqueueId);
Cursor c = dm.query(query);
if (c != null) {
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    //returns false
    }
}
```